# Facet Wrap in ggplot2 for my data and how to calculate P50?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, glm

I have the survival data (%) over time from my experiment. The data is as follows:

```
Survival <- read.table(text= "Species Var Year Time PerSurvival
1 1 2014 0 86
1 1 2014 1 74
1 1 2014 7 80
1 1 2014 14 69
1 1 2014 21 63
1 1 2014 28 52
1 1 2014 35 53
1 1 2014 42 47
1 1 2014 50 32
1 2 2015 0 99
1 2 2015 1 98
1 2 2015 7 95
1 2 2015 14 91
1 2 2015 21 60
1 2 2015 28 61
1 2 2015 35 48
1 2 2015 42 43
1 2 2015 50 10
1 3 2014 0 98
1 3 2014 1 97
1 3 2014 7 84
1 3 2014 14 82
1 3 2014 21 53
1 3 2014 28 52
1 3 2014 35 44
1 3 2014 42 29
1 3 2014 50 5
1 4 2014 0 92
1 4 2014 1 84
1 4 2014 7 78
1 4 2014 14 73
1 4 2014 21 57
1 4 2014 28 52
1 4 2014 35 46
1 4 2014 42 41
1 4 2014 50 13
2 5 2014 0 99
2 5 2014 1 97
2 5 2014 7 95
2 5 2014 14 86
2 5 2014 21 73
2 5 2014 28 76
2 5 2014 35 64
2 5 2014 42 29
2 5 2014 56 0
2 6 2015 0 94
2 6 2015 1 100
2 6 2015 7 90
2 6 2015 14 82
2 6 2015 21 76
2 6 2015 28 52
2 6 2015 35 50
2 6 2015 50 8
2 7 2014 0 98
2 7 2014 1 98
2 7 2014 7 96
2 7 2014 14 95
2 7 2014 21 82
2 7 2014 28 70
2 7 2014 35 81
2 7 2014 42 75
2 7 2014 50 9
2 8 2015 0 92
2 8 2015 1 94
2 8 2015 7 86
2 8 2015 14 84
2 8 2015 21 86
2 8 2015 28 78
2 8 2015 35 68
2 8 2015 50 53", header = TRUE)
```

I used the following code to visualise the data and fit logistic function:

```
View(Survival
attach(Survival)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=Survival) +
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Time,y=PerSurvival)) + xlim(0, 60) + ylim(0, 100) +
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=Time,y=PerSurvival), method="nls", formula = y ~ 100 / (1 + exp(-a* (x - b))), se = FALSE, fill=NA, method.args=list(start = c(a=-0.05, b=50))) +
  facet_wrap(~ Year + Var, nrow=2)
```

Running this code resulted in following graph:

[image: Survival Plots]

I need help for the following questions:

1. What code should be used to generate two separate plots for year 2014 and 2015. In plot for year 2014 there should be 5 curves for each var and in the year 2015 there should be 3 curves. How to colour the points and curve for each var or give different shape for the points for each curve?
2. What code should be used to generate plots in two rows, one each for years using facet wrap options? In such case in the top row there should be 5 individual plots with points and curve. Like wise the bottom row should have 3 curves?
3. How to derive time for 50% reduction in survival for each var? How to use dose.p function in Library(MASS)?

Comment: For no.2 you can use the package called ggarrange and the function ggrrange() for ggplots.   e.g `ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3,
          labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
          ncol = 3, nrow = 2, common.legend = T)`